# What does : mean in front of a path?

Tags: python, qt

For example:

`icon = QIcon(":icons/main.png")`

The "icons" directory was inside another directory outside the main program directory here:

/usr/share/ProgramName/design/icons/main.png

Comment: relative path from current compiling unit

Comment: http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/resources.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's a binary resource compiled into the program
as someone else linked:
[resource descriptions](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/resources.html)

is really all you need to read